# Python improving efficiency with a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

I have some code, which seems very repetitive and I was wondering how to icrease efficiency by putting it into a loop, despite the differences in variable names.

```
    if int(self.answer1) == int(self.studentAnswer1):
        self.score = int(self.score) + 1
        self.questionsAsked = self.questionsAsked + 1
        self.updateProgressBar()

    else:
        self.display = "Sorry the correct answer was " + str(self.answer1)
        self.wrongAnswer()

    self.correctAnswer = int(self.answer1)
    self.input = int(self.studentAnswer1)
    self.type = str(self.a) + " multiplied by 1000, to convert KG to Grams"
    self.insertAnswer()


    if int(self.answer2) == int(self.studentAnswer2):
        self.score = int(self.score) + 1
        self.questionsAsked = self.questionsAsked + 1
        self.updateProgressBar()

    else:
        self.display = "Sorry the correct answer was " + str(self.answer2)
        self.wrongAnswer()

    self.correctAnswer = int(self.answer2)
    self.input = int(self.studentAnswer2)
    self.type = str(self.a) + " divide by 1000, convert Grams to KG"
    self.insertAnswer()
```

It does currently as work as expected.

Comment: I don't see any loop.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel He is asking how to put it into a loop to remove redundancy

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the other answers, both of which iterate over indices and draw from lists, is using `zip`.

For example:

```
answers = [whatever]
student_answers = [whatever]
for answer, student_answer in zip(answers, student_answers):
  ...
```

This works exactly how it looks. `zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]) == [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
answer = [answer1, answer2];
student_answer= [studentAnswer1, studentAnswer2];

for i in range (len(answer)){
       if int(self.answer[i]) == int(self.student_answer[i]):
            self.score = int(self.score) + 1
            self.questionsAsked = self.questionsAsked + 1
            self.updateProgressBar()

        else:
            self.display = "Sorry the correct answer was " + str(self.answer[i])
            self.wrongAnswer()

        self.correctAnswer = int(self.answer[i])
        self.input = int(self.student_answer[i])
        self.type = str(self.a) + " multiplied by 1000, to convert KG to Grams"
        self.insertAnswer()
  }
```